# QEMU: weird display output when install debian on mac osx

Tags: linux, macos, display, debian, qemu

I got weird display when I tried to install debian on osx 10.9.1[image: qemu]

```
 qemu-system-i386 -hda debian.img -cdrom ~/Downloads/debian-testing-i386-netinst.iso -boot d
```

QEMU is the newest version brewed from Homebrew. There seems something incompatible with the display. Did anyone ever met this weird display output?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue here.